# Add Data field to Pivot based on cell

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create an interactive pivot table by allowing the user to select which data field to show (ie dollars earned, dollars spent).  I have the following code that works

```
Sub AddMoreFields()

 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
 .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
 "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Dollars_spent")
 End With

End Sub
```

However, i want to change it to something like the following, so that a user can select which data to show

```
Sub AddMoreFields()

 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
 .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
 "PivotTable1").PivotFields(Range("d21"))
 End With

End Sub
```

Range("D21") would actually be a drop down list in which a user could select between dollars earned and dollars spent.  However, when i try use this i get an error stating that Rang("D21") is not a pivot field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub adddynamic()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim f As String

f = Range("d21")
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields(f)
pt.AddDataField pf, "Sum of " & f, xlSum

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you describe a little the snippet you suggested? This creates searchable content and help your answer being viewed.